# Could not parse as expression title in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I get this trouble when using Thymeleaf.
My code :

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:replace="layout :: head(title=placeInfomation.getPlaceName())">
</head>
```

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "~{layout :: head(title=placeInfomation.getPlaceName())}" (template: "placeDetail" - line 3, col 7)
```

Comment: template: "placeDetail" - line 3, col 7

Comment: Not 100% sure whether it helps but have you tried evaluating placeInformation.getPlaceName() like a model attribute with the '$' sign? 'th:replace="layout :: head(title=${placeInfomation.getPlaceName()})"